# JSON, MVC3, and UTF-8 character encoding in AJAX

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, character-encoding

I'm posting JSON.stringify data to an MVC action and any UTF characters are coming through mangled despite setting the encoding in my javascript.  Here's what my jQuery call looks like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: BaseAppPath + "/Controller/Action",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify(jsonData),
    success: function (data) {
        // success code
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // error code
    }
});
```

My action definition looks something like this:

public JsonResult ModifyTaskStatus(int taskId, string note)

I have a breakpoint on the first line of the action.  At that time, the characters in the "note" parameter are hosed.  Everything up until the breakpoint handles the characters properly.  What do I need to do to ensure my action gets the chinese characters properly?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the POST data of the request with a tracing tool (Firebug, IE Developer Toolbar, Chrome Dev tools, etc.) Maybe post a screenshot of the results and the headers?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to mind is that your web application might not be setup for the same encoding.  Do you have a  element in your web.config? If not try adding to

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8"/>
```

Of course also make sure that your page has the content type set in the  tag via

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: I have both of those.  I also tried other forms of encoding, but the chinese characters still show up as squares in the first line of the action.